# Save User model in UserDefaults and append stored Users to array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a User model declared like this:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let nickname : String
    let fullName: String
    let profilePicUrl: URL
}
```

Then I save the followed user like this

```
let followedUser = User(nickname: username, fullName: fullName, profilePicUrl: url)
UserDefaults.standard.set(try! PropertyListEncoder().encode(followedUser), forKey: "user")
```

Next, in the ViewController which should display the followed users count I retrieve the UserDefaults data like this

```
var followedUsers = [User]()

if let storedObject: Data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "user") as? Data {
    do {
        let storedUser: User = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(User.self, from: storedObject)
        followedUsers.append(storedUser)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Now, my followedUsers array is being updated with the **last stored** user each time. How can I append my followedUsers array in a proper way?

Comment: **Now, my followedUsers array is being updated with the last stored user each time**  then what do you want instead ?. You are saving one record will always gives one record back !!

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya my array has only 1 element each time. It stores only the last user

Comment: Because You are saving only 1 record see this line `UserDefaults.standard.set...` ,`followedUser`

Comment: That's the issue, I don't how to save several records here in the proper way.Can you help me?

Comment: It is very simple. You have array of objects, you can convert into Data using `try JSONEncoder().encode(yourArrayOfUsers)`

Comment: You can try library I have created this will create file in your document directory  https://github.com/PrashantKT/Swift4-Locally-save-JSON-/blob/master/OfflineManager.swift

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Codable` , then it make sense to use `JSONEncoder` & `JSONDecoder` and store the users as an array

```
do { 
      // How to save multiple records 
      var followers = [User]() // Your array of users 
      let data =  try JSONEncoder().encode(followers) //Convert to Data
      UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "data") // Save to User Default 


     // How to fetch multiple records 
     // Check If data available in user default 
      if let da = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "data") {
        // Convert Data back to your cod-able struct 
        let stored = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: da)
      }

}
catch {
    print(error)
}

struct User: Codable {
    let nickname , fullName: String
    let profilePicUrl: URL
}
```

> Don't encourage using userDefault , you can go with **CoreData** / **Realm**

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya how ??

Comment: Try this in XCode

Comment: Do you think op will paste the `struct User: Codable {` there ? if so then it's a catastrophe

Comment: There is no issue of  where op will paste struct but   You have syntax error , JSONEncoder does not take any argument

Answer (score 1):

As @Sateesh and @Sanjukta said, storing the users in an array and saving that to UserDefaults is one solution.

The reason why your followedUsers array is updated with only one user, is that when you create a new user, you update the same key in UserDefaults each time.

It should be noted that UserDefaults is mainly used to store small amounts of data. Depending on how many User objects you plan to store, UserDefaults might not be the best solution.

The two solutions for data storage that come to mind are Core Data and Realm. Core Data is an Apple framework with which you can storage data on device. You can read more about it here: [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata)

The second option is to use Realm. Realm is is an open source database management system and can be used for on-device data storage too.

If you are interested in the differences between Realm and Core Data, for starters I can recommend [this](https://cocoacasts.com/core-data-or-realm) article.

Personally I use Realm in my own projects because I find it easier to implement and faster than Core Data. Please note that this is just my personal preference and others might disagree. Make sure you listen to other opinions and experiment with both before picking sides.

So let's suppose you want to store the User in Realm, you would need to do the following:

1. Install Realm for your project.

   - In your podfile add the following: `pod 'RealmSwift'`.
   - Run `pod install` in terminal and use the newly created `.xcworkspace` from now on.
2. In Xcode, in AppDelegate import RealmSwift and insert the following code to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

   ```
       do {
       _ = try Realm()
   } catch {
       print("Error initialising new Realm \(error)")
   }
   ```

This initializes a new default Realm, where your User data will be saved.

3. Create a new User.swift file. In that, import RealmSwift and insert the following:

   `class User: Object {
       @objc dynamic var nickName: String = ""
       @objc dynamic var fullName: String = ""
       @objc dynamic var profilePicURL: URL?
   }`

This creates a Realm object, which will contain the data for your users.

4. Save the followed user like this:

   - In the view controller where you want to save the user data import RealmSwift, and under the class declaration create a new instance of realm by `let realm = try! Realm()`
   - When you have the user data, save to Realm with the following code:

:

```
let followedUser = User()
    do{
        try realm.write {
            followedUser.nickName = username
            followedUser.fullName = fullName
            followedUser.profilePicURL = url
            realm.add(followedUser)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error saving to persistent container! \(error)")
    }
```

5. In the view controller where you need the user data, create an instance of Realm just like before with `let realm = try! Realm()`
   , retrieve users from Realm with the following code: `let followedUsers = realm.objects(User.self)`
   This retrieves all Users from the default realm.
   If you need to count the followedUsers you can do so by: `followedUsers.count`

Hopes this approach helps you to achieve what you wanted in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Please make the `array` of `object` then store the array in `userDefaults`.

After that you can easily retrive it.

It may help you. Thank you.